# How to count the number of unique numbers in sorted array using Binary Search?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, binary-search

I am trying to count the number of unique numbers in a sorted array using binary search. I need to get the edge of the change from one number to the next to count. I was thinking of doing this without using recursion. Is there an iterative approach?

```
def unique(x):
    start = 0
    end = len(x)-1
    count =0
    # This is the current number we are looking for
    item = x[start]

    while start <= end:
        middle = (start + end)//2
        
        if item == x[middle]:
            start = middle+1
            
        elif item < x[middle]:
            end = middle -1
        
        #when item item greater, change to next number
        count+=1

    # if the number
    return count
    
unique([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5])
```

Thank you.

Edit: Even if the runtime benefit is negligent from o(n), what is my binary search missing? It's confusing when not looking for an actual item. How can I fix this?

Comment: This isn't recursive. But I'm not sure it even works, you never change `item`.

Comment: It's returning `5` in your example, the correct answer is 3.

Comment: it's not counting unique values, it's counting the number of iterations of binary search it takes to find the first element.

Comment: @Barmar yes I said I am looking for an iterative approach. I fixed return value. Yes, I know it's wrong that's why I posted here.

Comment: What you need is a binary search function that just returns True or False to say whether the number is found. Then search for every number between `x[0]` and `x[-1]`, and count the number of successes.

Comment: A binary search is not the optimal way to get the number of unique elements from a sorted sequence.

Comment: @MarkRansom I want something better than o(n). I feel a binary search is the closest no?

Comment: To count the number of unique number, you have to pass through the entire list, I think o(n) is the minimum

Comment: @Colorful Codes Binary search approach works well when number of unique items is small, but in the worst case it works worse than linear scan

Comment: @thibsc I did that approach during a mock interview, and the guy told me there was a better way to do it than o(n). I thought of checking every other but he said better. So I mentioned a binary search and he told me to continue along those lines. I feel it is the right direction.

Comment: @MBo Is my sample input to large? I was told to imagine a list with "thousands" of numbers repeated and sorted.  Not sure which other algorithm makes sense here.

Comment: @ColorfulCodes, imagine the case where your list is sorted but all different, even with binary search, the complexity is not better

Comment: Seems that complexity for BS approach is `O(klogn)` where n is array size, k is number of unique items. When k is comparable with n, time becomes O(nlogn) - definitely slower than linear scan

Comment: @MBo if k is much less than n you could get an improvement in the overall time.  There may be be circumstances where that would be a reasonable assumption, but I wouldn't automatically assume that especially in an interview.

Comment: @MBo o(logn) is still better than o(n). That's improved.

Comment: @Colorful Codes  O(**k** log n). Consider case [1,2,3....999,1000, 2000, 2000, 2000...2000 (thousand times)]. You have to made 1001 binary search over range ~n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code exploiting binary search (returns 3 for given example).

As discussed in comments, complexity is about `O(k*log(n))` where k is number of unique items, so this approach works well **when k is small** compared with n, and might become worse than linear scan in case of  `k ~ n`

```
def countuniquebs(A):
    n = len(A)
    t = A[0]
    l = 1
    count = 0
    while l < n - 1:
        r = n - 1
        while l < r:
            m = (r + l) // 2
            if A[m] > t:
                r = m
            else:
                l = m + 1
        count += 1
        if l < n:
            t = A[l]
    return count

print(countuniquebs([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't quite call it "using a binary search", but this binary divide-and-conquer algorithm works in O(k*log(n)/log(k)) time, which is better than a repeated binary search, and never worse than a linear scan:

```
def countUniques(A, start, end):
    len = end-start
    if len < 1:
        return 0
    if A[start] == A[end-1]:
        return 1
    if len < 3:
        return 2
    mid = start + len//2
    return countUniques(A, start, mid+1) + countUniques(A, mid, end) - 1

A = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
print(countUniques(A,0,len(A)))
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution. Can you explain a bit about why the runtime ends up being O(k*log(n)/log(k))? This seems right since as k approaches N, the runtime approaches O(N).